# 2+ events for the same trigger in Firebase like jquery

Tags: jquery, events, firebase

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a trigger for both `child_changed` and `child_moved` in **Firebase**, just like in jQuery:

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function() {
    ...
});
```

This is what I tried doing with Firebase's function:

```
var ref = firebase.orderByPriority().on('child_changed child_moved', function(push) {
    ...
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you'll need to attach a handler for each event separately.

But this will work of course:

```
var callback = function(push) {
    ...
};
firebase.orderByPriority().on('child_changed', callback);
firebase.orderByPriority().on('child_moved', callback);
```

Also keep in mind that `child_moved` will always have a corresponding `child_changed` event. So you may only need to hook one of them.